# Update Intero flycheck after changing cabal file

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-mode, intero

I am using Intero under emacs to edit my new Haskell project. I added an import to a third-party library to my code to see if Intero would automatically add the necessary dependency, but it didn't. So I edited the `.cabal` file manually to add the necessary dependency. Now what do I do - short of restarting emacs?

I've tried running `cabal install --dependencies-only; cabal configure` at the command line and they ran successfully, but the flycheck buffer still shows an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All that is necessary is to run

```
M-x intero-restart
```

in emacs.

Intero uses stack which has its own private sandbox for each package you are developing, so `cabal install --dependencies-only` isn't needed or useful.

Comment: I knew about `intero-restart` but it doesn't seem to affect an open intero-ghci session. I currently need to close the buffer to force the ghci buffer to pick the changes. Do you know anything about that ?

Comment: I don't think ghci can reload binary dependencies, so it would be necessary to restart ghci in any case.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue: I added new dependencies in cabal file and can't get my module to pass compilation. When I do `C-c C-l` I get compilation error. I've tried to do `intero-restart` but didn't work... Any ideas?

Comment: Here's the [output](https://gist.github.com/galderz/20696510d29ab68348b9a36f479bba79).

Comment: Actually, my bad, I had put the file in the wrong place.